# Javascript, HP reload after alert wihout URL

Tags: php, javascript, flash, forms, reload

I have an html form within a flash site. The form is php processed.  Help me fix the php file so that after processing the form, the php returns the user to the flash page and reloads the html form.   I tried a window.location in the php to send to the page but that did not work.  It results in a white rectangle within the html code area (maybe frame but I'm not sure).  How can I get just that html form reloaded?  I do not want to load the entire page using a URL because that is too slow and I cannot replicate the flash state.  BTW, below is a stripped down version of the code to simplify.

URL: 
    http://www.wix.com/efficertain/efficertainaccounting/accounting

Form Code:
    
    Name 
    Phone 
    Best time to call

PHP Code:

```
$mail_to = 'info@efficertain.ca';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_when;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'http://www.wix.com/efficertain/efficertainaccounting/accounting';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@efficertain.ca');
    window.location = 'http://www.wix.com/efficertain/efficertainaccounting/accounting';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `window.location` here as it will reload the whole browser window. Try to use `document.location` and you will need to pass it the URL of your form instead of the URL for the whole page as you only want to reload the iframe content. So your URL would be `http://www.flashquix.com/embeds/fb4c83282b9342aa83952e74ad33dfdd?wrap=no&gzip=true&bg=transparent` according to the example above.

```
document.location = 'http://www.flashquix.com/embeds/fb4c83282b9342aa83952e74ad33dfdd?wrap=no&gzip=true&bg=transparent';
```

Comment: Thanks bardiir. Worked great. Now I am trying to get the URL in the form and transfer to the php because the php will be used with multiple sources. Not working. Likely a beginner's syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are already putting new content on the page.. just follow the logic and make that content your form.

```
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to info@efficertain.ca');
</script>
// INSERT YOUR FORM HTML HERE AND YOU'RE GOOD TO GO
```